# Создать дерево на основе массива полученного из события(Java)

Tags: java, swing

уважаемые программисты и кодеры, буду очень признателен если поможете с возникшим у меня вопросом, а именно:
В результате нажатия кнопки генерируется событие, в котором идет перебор файлов и отбираются файлы определенного формата, одновременно с чем все эти файлы помещаются в массив, однако этот массив остается внутри события и вызвать его ни посредством сэтеров/гетеров не является возможным(т.к. получается метод в методе), ни каким либо другим способом из мной перепробованных тоже не удается. А на основе полученных файлов нужно сформировать дерево, а из-за невозможности обратиться к массиву это у меня никак не получается. Как это всё можно реализовать? 
Достаточно будет просто пути решения, реализовать я постараюсь сам, хотя буду счастлив получить готовый паттерн или шаблон. Заранее спасибо всем откликнувшимся!!

Comment: Разместите код этих методов, так будет проще понять что за структура у Вас такая недоступная.

Comment: Возможно дело в области видимости переменной массива, попробуйте объявить ее вне метода обработки нажатия кнопки, и передавайте в метод как параметр. Или, как вариант, объявите ее вообще статической.

Comment: Да, все получилось, спасибо огромное!!